# Using Pandas to group data based on name and see if column value is greater than or equal to values based on group names

Tags: python, excel, pandas

As you'll see from the below code, I'm creating separate data frames of a much larger data frame, then updating a column for each one. What I'm doing is looking at the second column and checking to see if it meets a certain threshold value that is associated with the brand name found within the first column that has each individual hotel's name (part of that whole hotel name contains the specific brand name so I use .contains to group each of these hotels by brand name into specific data frame). Finally, I merge all of them together to get the original data frame with the updated column "Meeting/Not Meeting" column. When I've tried making a change only to the "splice" of the data frame associated with the rows that I'm interested in applying a certain threshold comparison to, it overwrites the previous values of the column with blank values, so this was the best solution I could come up with my limited knowledge.

Another thing I want to improve is the repetitiveness of the below code. I'm rewriting so much it seems and I'm sure there is a much better way of doing the following.

Here's an example of the data:
[image: sample data]

Raw text if that's more helpful:

Property|   Overall Experience| Meeting /Not Meeting

Hotel Portland  76
Hotel Suites Los Angeles    49
Hotel Suites Colorado Springs   80
Hotel Premium Denver    82
Hotel Premium Miami Extended Stay   70
Extended Stay Phoenix   65
Hotel Suites Redwood Extended Stay  81
Nexus Santa Barbara 92
Plaza by the Sea    77
Majestic By Hilltop 90
Majestic San Francisco  85
Hotel Seattle   56

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files

# file uploaded here and name extracted
uploaded = files.upload()
filename = next(iter(uploaded))

df = pd.read_excel(filename)

# separate dfs for each brand name since they have their own threshold value for Overall Experience guest rating
hotel_core_df = df.loc[(df['Property'].str.contains('Hotel')) & ~(df['Property'].str.contains('Hotel Suites')) & ~(df['Property'].str.contains('Hotel Premium'))].copy()
hotel_core_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = hotel_core_df['Overall Experience'] >= 72.10

# if Extended Stay in name - treat as Extended Stay brand even if Suites or Premium property
hotel_suites_df = df.loc[df['Property'].str.contains('Hotel Suites') & ~(df['Property'].str.contains('Extended Stay'))].copy()
hotel_suites_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = hotel_suites_df['Overall Experience'] >= 74.65

hotel_prem_df = df.loc[df['Property'].str.contains('Hotel Premium') & ~(df['Property'].str.contains('Extended Stay'))].copy()
hotel_prem_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = hotel_prem_df['Overall Experience'] >= 75.71

nexus_df = df.loc[df['Property'].str.contains('Nexus')].copy()
nexus_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = nexus_df['Overall Experience'] >= 74.82

plaza_df = df.loc[df['Property'].str.contains('Plaza')].copy()
plaza_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = plaza_df['Overall Experience'] >= 73.82

extend_df = df.loc[df['Property'].str.contains('Extended Stay')].copy()
extend_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = extend_df['Overall Experience'] >= 74.82

majestic_df = df.loc[df['Property'].str.contains('Majestic')].copy()
majestic_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = majestic_df['Overall Experience'] >= 75.78

merged_df = pd.concat([hotel_core_df, hotel_suites_df, hotel_prem_df, nexus_df, plaza_df, extend_df, majestic_df])
merged_df.sort_values(by=['Overall Experience'], ascending=False, inplace=True)

merged_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: 'Meeting' if x['Meeting /Not Meeting'] == True else 'Not Meeting',axis=1)
    
merged_df.to_excel('OE threshold.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Can you show an example data file? Otherwise we will not be able to run this.

Comment: Based on the actual data, you may or may not need to break vectorisation and do a looped or mapped regular expression match. But it's impossible to say without seeing the real thing.

Comment: I added an example of the data above.

Comment: `Plaza Hotel by the Sea` is ambiguous. Which record should it match?

Comment: Good catch. I made a mistake. Obviously I didn't want to use real data and names so I typed that sample out myself. Neither Plaza Hotel or Nexus Hotel should contain Hotel. I updated it above. Hopefully, I didn't make any other errors.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to rethink your required experience criteria as a merge between a criteria table and a hotel records table. For your existing data, the easiest way to do this is a priority substring match. This is less repetitive than what you have now, but I have not tested its performance.

Also, you should probably skip this altogether:

```py
merged_df['Meeting /Not Meeting'] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: 'Meeting' if x['Meeting /Not Meeting'] == True else 'Not Meeting',axis=1)
```

Real booleans are better than strings.

### Suggested

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Property': [
        'Hotel', 'Hotel Suites', 'Hotel Premium', 'Nexus', 'Plaza', 'Extended Stay',
        'Majestic', 'Majestic', 'Hotel Portland', 'Hotel Suites Los Angeles',
        'Hotel Suites Colorado Springs', 'Hotel Premium Denver',
        'Hotel Premium Miami Extended Stay', 'Extended Stay Phoenix',
        'Hotel Suites Redwood Extended Stay', 'Nexus Santa Barbara',
        'Plaza by the Sea', 'Majestic By Hilltop', 'Majestic San Francisco',
        'Hotel Seattle',
    ],
    'Overall Experience': [
        75, 74, 74, 76, 76, 76, 71, 77,
        76, 49, 80, 82, 70, 65, 81, 92,
        77, 90, 85, 56],
})
df.index.name = 'record'

# Decreasing order of priority
criteria = pd.DataFrame({
    'required_experience': [74.82, 74.65, 75.71, 74.82, 73.82, 75.78, 72.10],
    'property_term': ['extended', 'suites', 'premium', 'nexus', 'plaza', 'majestic', 'hotel'],
})
criteria.index.name = 'priority'

# Long-form series of hotel term words, with nulls dropped
terms = df.Property.str.lower().str.split(expand=True).stack()
terms.name = 'property_term'
terms.index.names = ('record', 'term_index')

# Merged dataframe between terms and criteria, with ambiguity resolved by taking first term in priority sequence
keep_cols = ['property_term', 'required_experience']
merged = (
    pd.merge(left=terms.reset_index(), right=criteria.reset_index(), on='property_term')
    .sort_values(by=['record', 'priority'])
    .set_index('record')
    .groupby(level='record').first()
)[keep_cols]

df[keep_cols] = merged
df['Meeting'] = df['Overall Experience'] >= df.required_experience

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
print(df)
```

```
                                  Property  Overall Experience property_term  required_experience  Meeting
record                                                                                                    
0                                    Hotel                  75         hotel                72.10     True
1                             Hotel Suites                  74        suites                74.65    False
2                            Hotel Premium                  74       premium                75.71    False
3                                    Nexus                  76         nexus                74.82     True
4                                    Plaza                  76         plaza                73.82     True
5                            Extended Stay                  76      extended                74.82     True
6                                 Majestic                  71      majestic                75.78    False
7                                 Majestic                  77      majestic                75.78     True
8                           Hotel Portland                  76         hotel                72.10     True
9                 Hotel Suites Los Angeles                  49        suites                74.65    False
10           Hotel Suites Colorado Springs                  80        suites                74.65     True
11                    Hotel Premium Denver                  82       premium                75.71     True
12       Hotel Premium Miami Extended Stay                  70      extended                74.82    False
13                   Extended Stay Phoenix                  65      extended                74.82    False
14      Hotel Suites Redwood Extended Stay                  81      extended                74.82     True
15                     Nexus Santa Barbara                  92         nexus                74.82     True
16                        Plaza by the Sea                  77         plaza                73.82     True
17                     Majestic By Hilltop                  90      majestic                75.78     True
18                  Majestic San Francisco                  85      majestic                75.78     True
19                           Hotel Seattle                  56         hotel                72.10    False
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test this out. This already seems a lot better that what I was doing and will help me avoid repetition with future tasks. I'm sure there are easier ways of doing this directly in Excel, but I haven't worked with it as much so Python seemed like a good alternative. I completely agree with skipping the Boolean to string conversion. The only reason I did that is because the string format is what the rest of the team I'm sharing this data with will likely be expecting.